# CSS/JS expanding three-level dropdown navigation, third sub menu items not clickable and just closing parent LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do recall a while back fixing this but reverted somehow, but from memory and debugging in console I think it is the parent LI that is wrapping making the whole area clickable (setup console.log and returns log for 2nd level so think this is the issue but could be wrong) and css is the issue I think.

To see/replicate in example click on SHOP, then WASH it is the sub-items I'm getting the problem... click one and just closes.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hostandname/bz9cfp8u/26/ (stripped down to CSS/JS but can reproduce the problem all the same)

**HTML**

```
<body class="website-wrapper af-ajax-shop-on template-index af-top-bar-on header-full-width enable-sticky-header sticky-header-real no-sticky-footer wrapper-full-width global-search-full-screen af-ajax-search-on gl-tab-js global-header-split global-cart-design-3 catalog-mode-off sticky-header-prepared document-ready is-mobile af-wrapper-shifted af-mobile-opened">
<header class="container-fluid main-header header-split menu-calculated color-scheme-light">
  <div class="main-nav site-navigation af-navigation menu-center d-md-none d-lg-block nav-mobile">

    <ul class="menu parent-1">
      <li class="list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-1"><a href="/en/" title="Home" data-status="1" data-menu-id="10" data-parent-id="0">Home</a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-1 has-sub-menu"><a href="/en/shop-the-lot" title="Shop" data-status="1" data-menu-id="11" data-parent-id="0">Shop</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu level-11 parent-2">
          <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-2 has-sub-menu"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash" title="Wash" data-status="0" data-menu-id="2" data-parent-id="11">Wash</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu level-2 parent-3">
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/pre-wash" title="Pre Wash" data-status="0" data-menu-id="95" data-parent-id="2">Pre Wash</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/snow-foams" title="Snow Foam" data-status="0" data-menu-id="94" data-parent-id="2">Snow Foam</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/decontamination" title="Decontamination" data-status="0" data-menu-id="98" data-parent-id="2">Decontamination</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/cleaners" title="Cleaners" data-status="0" data-menu-id="145" data-parent-id="2">Cleaners</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/shampoos" title="Shampoos" data-status="0" data-menu-id="96" data-parent-id="2">Shampoos</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/wash-mitts" title="Wash Mitts" data-status="0" data-menu-id="99" data-parent-id="2">Wash Mitts</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/wheels" title="Wheels" data-status="0" data-menu-id="103" data-parent-id="2">Wheels</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/engine-bay" title="Engine Bay" data-status="0" data-menu-id="144" data-parent-id="2">Engine Bay</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/rinse-aids" title="Rinse Aids" data-status="0" data-menu-id="100" data-parent-id="2">Rinse Aids</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/drying-towels" title="Drying Towels" data-status="0" data-menu-id="102" data-parent-id="2">Drying Towels</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/brushes" title="Brushes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="142" data-parent-id="2">Brushes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash/wash-kits" title="Wash Kits" data-status="0" data-menu-id="132" data-parent-id="2">Wash Kits</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col view-all-link list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/wash" title="View all Wash" data-status="0" data-menu-id="151" data-parent-id="2">View all Wash</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-2 has-sub-menu"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish" title="Polish" data-status="0" data-menu-id="3" data-parent-id="11">Polish</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu level-3 parent-3">
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/hand-polishes" title="Hand Polishes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="119" data-parent-id="3">Hand Polishes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/glazes" title="Glazes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="106" data-parent-id="3">Glazes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/machine-polishers" title="Machine Polishers" data-status="0" data-menu-id="108" data-parent-id="3">Machine Polishers</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/paint-correction" title="Paint Correction" data-status="0" data-menu-id="109" data-parent-id="3">Paint Correction</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/metal-polish" title="Metal Polish" data-status="0" data-menu-id="107" data-parent-id="3">Metal Polish</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/pads" title="Pads" data-status="0" data-menu-id="110" data-parent-id="3">Pads</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/applicators" title="Applicators" data-status="0" data-menu-id="111" data-parent-id="3">Applicators</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish/polish-kits" title="Polish Kits" data-status="0" data-menu-id="133" data-parent-id="3">Polish Kits</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col view-all-link list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/polish" title="View all Polish" data-status="0" data-menu-id="152" data-parent-id="3">View all Polish</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-2 has-sub-menu"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect" title="Protect" data-status="0" data-menu-id="147" data-parent-id="11">Protect</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu level-147 parent-3">
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect/ceramic-coatings" title="Ceramic Coatings" data-status="0" data-menu-id="117" data-parent-id="147">Ceramic Coatings</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect/hand-waxes" title="Hand Waxes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="121" data-parent-id="147">Hand Waxes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/finishing/spray-wax-detailers" title="Spray Waxes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="122" data-parent-id="147">Spray Waxes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect/wheel-waxes" title="Wheel Waxes" data-status="0" data-menu-id="124" data-parent-id="147">Wheel Waxes</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect/cloths-applicators" title="Cloths &amp; Applicators" data-status="0" data-menu-id="125" data-parent-id="147">Cloths &amp; Applicators</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect/protect-kits" title="Wax Kits" data-status="0" data-menu-id="123" data-parent-id="147">Wax Kits</a></li>
              <li class="flex-column col view-all-link list-inline-item block_type_no_children menu-item menu-item-design-default item-event-hover child-3"><a href="DEBUG/en/protect" title="View all Protect" data-status="0" data-menu-id="156" data-parent-id="147">View all Protect</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var JSModule;
var isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop;

(function($) {
  "use strict";

  JSModule = (function() {

    return {

      init: function() {

        this.checkDevice();
        this.menuSetUp();

        $('body').addClass('document-ready');

        var resizeTimer, isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop;

      },

      /***---------------------
       * Mobile / Viewport Checking
       *------------------------
      */

      checkDevice: function() {

        var checkSize = function() {
          var body = $('body'),
            viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
            device,
            classes = "is-mobile is-tablet is-desktop";

          if (viewportWidth < 768) {
            // mobile
            body.removeClass(classes).addClass("is-mobile");

            isMobile = true;
            isTablet = false;
            isDesktop = false;
            device = 'mobile';
          } else if (viewportWidth >= 768 && viewportWidth < 992) {
            // tablet
            body.removeClass(classes).addClass("is-tablet");
            isMobile = false;
            isTablet = true;
            isDesktop = false;
            device = 'tablet';
          } else if (viewportWidth >= 992 && viewportWidth < 1200) {
            // laptops
            body.removeClass(classes).addClass("is-desktop");
            isMobile = false;
            isTablet = false;
            isDesktop = true;
            device = 'desktop';
          } else {
            // desktops
            body.removeClass(classes).addClass("is-desktop");
            isMobile = false;
            isTablet = false;
            isDesktop = true;
            device = 'desktop';
          }

        }

        checkSize();
        $(window).on('resize', checkSize);
      },


      /***----------------------------------
       * Menu Preparation
       *------------------------------------
      */

      menuSetUp: function() {

        var addLevelClass = function($parent, level) {
          // add a parent class to the ul
          $parent.addClass('parent-' + level);
          // fetch all the li's that are direct children of the ul
          var $children = $parent.children('li');
          // add a child class to the li
          $children.addClass('child-' + level);
          // loop trough each li
          $children.each(function() {
            // get the ul that is a direct child of the li
            var $sublist = $(this).children('ul');
            // if an ul was found
            if ($sublist.length > 0) {
              // add a class to the current li indicating there is a sub list
              if (!$(this).hasClass('is-section')) {
                $(this).addClass('has-sub-menu');
              }
              addLevelClass($sublist, level + 1);
            }
          });
        }

        addLevelClass($('.af-navigation .menu'), 1);

        var mainMenu = $('.af-navigation .menu');

        if (isMobile || isTablet) {

          mainMenu.on('click touchstart', 'li.has-sub-menu.child-1', function(e) {
            console.log("1st clicked");
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('show');
          });

          mainMenu.on('click touchstart', 'li.has-sub-menu.child-2', function(e) {
            console.log("2nd clicked");
            e.stopPropagation();

            $(this).toggleClass('show');

            if (isMobile || isTablet) {
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          });

          mainMenu.on('click touchstart', 'li.has-sub-menu.child-2 .child-3, li.is-section.child-2 .child-3', function(e) {
            console.log("3rd clicked");

            return true;
          });
        }

      }
    }

  }());

})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  JSModule.init();

  var resizeTimer, isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop;

  $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      JSModule.init();
    }, 250);
  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
header.header-split .main-nav .menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0 !important
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li.list-inline-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: .8em 2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-table
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #00888b
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>a:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0)
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #ebebeb;
  padding: 3em 2em;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-135%);
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  height: 100vh;
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-out
}

@media (max-width:767.98px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul {
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1
  }
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul {
    transition: none
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li {
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: .08em
}

@media (max-width:767.98px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a {
    padding: .5em 0 !important
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block {
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  font-family: Brandon-bold, 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 !important
}

@media (max-width:767.98px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block {
    margin-bottom: 1em
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block img {
  -webkit-opacity: .6;
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.1em
}

@media (min-width:1800px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block span {
    font-size: 1.25em
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li a.menu-image-block:hover img {
  -webkit-opacity: .8;
  -moz-opacity: .8;
  opacity: .8;
  transition: opacity .5s ease 50ms
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li .sub-menu li {
  display: contents
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li .sub-menu li a {
  color: #555;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: .75em 0 0 0
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li .sub-menu li a:hover {
  color: #00888b
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul.sub-menu li .sub-menu li.view-all-link a {
  color: #00888b
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .5em 0;
  font-family: Brandon-bold, 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: .08em;
  background-color: #ebebeb
}

@media (max-width:767.98px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li a:before {
    display: none
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li ul li {
  display: block
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li ul li a {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-family: MuseoSans-300, 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li>ul li ul li a:before {
  display: none
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li:hover {
  color: #00888b
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0)
}

@media (max-width:767.98px) {
  header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li:hover>ul {
    display: block
  }
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li:hover a {
  color: #00888b
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li.item-event-hover:hover>.sub-menu-dropdown {
  top: 100%
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu>li.item-event-click.item-menu-opened>.sub-menu-dropdown {
  top: 100%
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu .menu-item .sub-menu-dropdown:after {
  height: 25px
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu .callto-btn.menu-item-design-sized .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 0
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu .callto-btn.menu-item-design-default .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 0
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-sized .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 25px
}

header.header-split .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-default .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 25px
}

header.header-split .main-nav .sub-menu-dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%
}

header.header-split.menu-calculated .main-nav {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu>li:hover>ul {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0)
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu .menu-item .sub-menu-dropdown:after {
  height: 15px
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-sized .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 15px
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu .menu-item-design-default .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 15px
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu .callto-btn.menu-item-design-sized .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 0
}

header.header-split.act-scroll .main-nav .menu .callto-btn.menu-item-design-default .sub-menu-dropdown {
  margin-top: 0
}

af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu {
  padding: 0
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li {
  display: block !important;
  text-align: left
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu:before {
  color: #282828;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 Autofinesse;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\f05d";
  float: right;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20%);
  transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  right: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu.show:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateY(0);
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(0);
  transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .25s ease-in-out
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li>ul {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  position: relative !important;
  height: auto !important
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li a {
  padding: 1em 2em !important;
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  line-height: initial !important;
  color: #222 !important
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li a:hover {
  color: #00888b
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 {
  display: none;
  z-index: auto
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li {
  display: block !important
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li a {
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.5em !important;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li.has-sub-menu:last-child a {
  border-bottom: 0
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li .sub-menu.parent-3 {
  display: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
  z-index: auto
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li .sub-menu.parent-3 li {
  display: block
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li .sub-menu.parent-3 li a {
  border: 0;
  padding: .6em 1em .6em 1em !important
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li.is-section {
  padding-top: .5em
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li.is-section .sub-menu.parent-3 {
  z-index: auto
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li.is-section .sub-menu.parent-3 li a {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li.is-section:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-top: 0
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu .sub-menu.parent-2 li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: 0
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu.show .sub-menu.parent-2 {
  display: block
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu.show .sub-menu.parent-2 li .sub-menu.parent-3 {
  display: none
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.has-sub-menu.show .sub-menu.parent-2 li.show .sub-menu.parent-3 {
  display: block
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.is-section ul {
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin: 0 !important
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.is-section ul li {
  padding: 0
}

.af-mobile-opened .main-nav .menu li.is-section ul li a.menu-image-block {
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  color: #fff !important
}

.main-nav .menu>li>a {
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px
}

.act-scroll .main-nav .menu>li>a {
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px
}
```

Comment: Just looking at the behavior, you're not stopping the click event on the sub sub element from propagating.  So it's bubbling up to the sub menu element and causing it to toggle closed.

Comment: I did remove e.stopPropagation(); from 3rd one other dasy for testing and forgot to put it back but with that was not working, will update fiddle to make sure now

Comment: Hmm seems to work as expected in fiddle, swear was not before but just trying on main script / system now... give me a moment lol

Comment: Ok yea, working now.... hmm weird lol swear only recently removed to test but putting it back seems to be playing ball now. If you want to add the solution happy to give you the vote but the second pair of eyes has helped clearly! Knew would be something stupid! thanks mate

Comment: Since all I did was describe the behavior and the possible solution, I would be more inclined to encourage you to self answer your question in detail of what the issue was and how you fixed it.

Comment: will do, im first doing to deploy to staging so can test on a real mobile native device to make sure working rather than adjusting viewport size in browser to double check so once done that will post the solution.... still confused though as was not working with the stopPropagation but when added back seemed to have worked lol ive prob played with the CSS since maybe or something else and resolved it but did not know hahaha thanks again mate, was brain dead on this for ages... you know how it is, too long on a bug you just gone crazy lol thanks again

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of Typo/Unreproducible: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.